# Boost path to file in directory pointed by a path

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I have a boost path that points to some directory.
How do I construct a path that points to a file in that directory?

Please comment if this is an obvious thing. Im new to C++ and in Java it's this easy:

```
File file = new File(theDirectory, "filename.txt");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [append](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-appends) e.g.

```
path /= filename;
```

Answer (score 2):

Path has a convenience `operator/` that you may find useful for this purpose:

```
auto file = directory / "filename";
```